# VisualStudio - How to unattended install a 3rd party DLL control?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, controls, toolbox, unattended-processing

I'm trying to make a deployment of vs2012,

The extensions are too easy to install because they are in VSIX format so i can call them silently,

The question is how can I install a DLL control in my VS without opening the "choose toolbox items..." menu?

It's posibbly?

Maybe exist a special folder like the snippets folder where you put some snippets and VS automatically recognices the new added snippets?

Or maybe i need to create a VSIX installer for each of my 3rd party DLL controls? Then someone can give me a little info about that?

Thankyou for read

**UPDATE**: i get this error trying the custom build of toolbox manager:

PD: i'm using win 64 bit, and i've tryed at least all the command combinations for this tool.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a tutorial article on toolbox control installation in Visual Studio, including VS2012:

[Visual Studio Toolbox Control Integration](http://www.componentowl.com/articles/visual-studio-toolbox-control-integration)

It contains several approaches and compares them so you can choose the one most suitable to you.

Comment: thanks for comment, but i can't find a download link for DTE!

Comment: I can't find a donload link for TCI of DTE tools... and in your article are incompleted parts, (for example this necessary key for me) is incomplete:Installing in Visual Studio 2012

One extra step is required to make this work in Visual Studio 2012, which is adding the registry key also in its user config hive, i.e.:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\ToolboxControlsInstaller\SampleControl, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutra        can you modify it please?

Comment: I have [updated the article](http://www.componentowl.com/articles/visual-studio-toolbox-control-integration#source) adding the download link. I have tested all the approaches with both VS2010 and VS2012. The required additional registry key is mentioned in the article. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Could you update the DteToolboxInstaller tool to be compatible with VS2013 Ultimate installation, please? I'm really lost...

Comment: No matter, I did the necessary modifications to the source by myself and worked like a charm!.

Comment: @ElektroStudios Thanks. I didn't have time to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but... My alternative solution for people who can't run toolbox.exe for VS2012:

PS: This bat file is based on another bat but I've lost the reference link for credits, mine have error control and is more customizable.

```
@Echo OFF
Title Control Installer v1.0

REM By Elektro H@cker  
REM This tool performs installation of new controls for VisualStudio.


REM Syntax:
:: Control_Installer.cmd "Name of dll" "Name of tab" "Controls folder (THIS IS OPTIONAL)" "DEVENV.exe folder (THIS IS OPTIONAL)"


Set "DLLFILE=%~1"
Set "TABNAME=%~2"
IF "%~3" EQU "" (SET "CONTROLSFOLDER=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Controls") ELSE (SET "CONTROLSFOLDER=%~3")
IF "%~4" EQU "" (SET "VSFOLDER=%VS110COMNTOOLS%\..\IDE\")                                  ELSE (SET "VSFOLDER=%~4")


IF NOT EXIST "%DLLFILE%"              (Echo: An error occurred: Can't find the controls file "%DLLFILE%". & Exit /B 1)
IF NOT EXIST "%CONTROLSFOLDER%"       (Echo: An error occurred: Can't find the controls folder "%ControlsFolder%". & Exit /B 1)
IF NOT EXIST "%VSFOLDER%\devenv.exe"  (Echo: An error occurred: Can't find the VisualStudio "devenv.exe" in "%VSFOLDER%". & Exit /B 1)
IF "%TABNAME%" EQU ""                 (Echo: An error occurred: Can't crate the tab "%TABNAME%". & Exit /B 1)


MKDIR "%ControlsFolder%\%TABNAME%"                2>NUL
Copy /Y "%DLLFILE%" "%ControlsFolder%\%TABNAME%\" 1>NUL
Start /B /D "%VSFOLDER%" devenv.exe /command Tools.InstallCommunityControls && Exit /B 0 || (Exit /B 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my update of @Libor work

I've translated all the code to VB.NET, added compatibility with VS2013, experimental compatibility with WPF controls.

Credits for the original author above.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is more info:

www.google.com/translate?hl=en&ie=UTF8&sl=es&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fforo.elhacker.net%2Fnet%2Fsource_extended_dte_toolbox_control_installer-t406027.0.html%3Bmsg1909162%23msg1909162

Here is the source:

http://elektrostudios.tk/Extended%20DTE%20Toolbox%20Control%20Installer.zip